# emacs sql-mode: how to scroll the the output window after run the sql?

Tags: emacs, sql-mode

I am pretty happy with emacs sql-mode with vertica. But one problem is after run the sql using C-c C-c, ifoutput window is full of text, and the output text I want to see in not visible, so I have to jump to the output window, scroll down to the bottom to see the result. Is there anyway to scroll down automatically? like tail -f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try turning on `auto-revert-tail-mode` for that buffer, though I've only used this with buffers that are linked to files. This works just like `tail -f`.

Alternatively, you could also use `scroll-other-window`, bound to `C-M-v` by default, to scroll your SQL output window from your main one.